# How do I apply a string function to an array?

Tags: php, string

I was fortunate enough to receive this code (flips Lastname, Firstname) from an earlier post.

```
$name = "Lastname, Firstname";
$names = explode(", ", $name);
$name = $names[1] . " " . $names[0];
```

How do I apply the function to each value in an array that is in the form: `$ginfo ->$(LastName, FirstName)`.

I tried the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
$name1 =($ginfo->White); 
$name1 = explode(", ", $name1);  $FLw = $name1[1] . " " . $name1[0]; 
foreach ($name1 as ($ginfo->White)) {return($FLw);}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function:

```
function transpose($name)
{
    $names = explode(", ", $name);
    return $names[1] . " " . $names[0];
}

$transposed_array = array_map("transpose", $your_array);
```

Comment: +1, removed my answer, there wasn't any difference with mine.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I've been sweating this one out for a while and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: The value I have for "$your_array" as written in the code is a table column ($ginfo->$names).  I can't find a way to include it in the syntax above.